# Web service response compression

Tags: wcf, soap, compression

i'm trying understand what are consequences of enabling compression for web service response. 
Web service is implemented as IIS hosted WCF service with http binding. I would like to add compression on http level, so it should be seamless for clients. Soap response size is in 100kb - 1Mb range. We do this to improve user experience on low-bandwidth network. What are  drawbacks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

100kb - 1Mb : Are you sending some form of binary data in your response such as files? In this case you can consider using [MTOM](http://mssolutionhelper.com/topics/dotnet/WCF_MTOM.aspx) which will optimize responses.

If it is only text then you could gain pretty much bandwidth by compressing the response. The only drawback I can think of is that it will not be interoperable (both server and clients need to implement it) and it will probably incur some CPU overhead.

Answer (score 1):

In my reading on this topic, what you are proposing is only seamless when the WCF client is Silverlight, because the browser then implements the client-side portion of the compression handshake.  With a standard .net client, you would need additional code in place to make this work.